# Is it possible to create key of map of type map?

Tags: java

I would like to create a `LinkedMap` which the key is of type `Map` too, like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<LinkedHashMap<String, Float>, String> map = 
       new LinkedHashMap <LinkedHashMap<String, Float>, String>
```

Is it possible or not? If yes: how can I call for Keys and Values of Map Key?

Comment: What's the problem with trying this?

Comment: yes you can do this. Since it expect the key to be object.

Comment: if it compiles, it's possible -> the main java secret >)

Comment: @injecteer Not always. For example, [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).

Comment: @injecteer: define 'possible'. Runtime exceptions are nasty.

Comment: in this context it IS

Comment: @injecteer Yes, but we were referring other context ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun WHAAAT?! :)) Anyways, you have to try hard to break it. You must be familiar with java for that. Meaning you would never ask such a question :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can you give an example of the data you're trying to track?

Comment: So, the value of map is refered to all "map key" or it is possible to relate each value (String) to one instance of the "Map key" (<String, Float>?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `Map` which takes another `Map` as a key, then you will have an unstable `Map`, since adding or removing keys/values from any of the `Maps` that you're using a keys will change their hashcodes.  So, you should **NEVER** do this.  Keys should not have changing hashcodes!

Comment: but I need to register information <Sentences, Score> in class 1, than I should use them in class 2 whith saving to each instances <Sentence, Score> an other criterion <Type>, there not other solution.

Comment: If you can 100% guarantee that your maps' hashcodes will never change, then you can do this, but I highly recommend against it without that guarantee... There's always another way to do it, it just may not be as fast, which may not matter for your particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.

`LinkedHashMap<LinkedHashMap<String, Float>, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();` (Java 7 notation)

But as your key in map is an map you it will be really hard to access it as you will need to provide most probably same instance only to retrieve a String value. And the debug will be really hard too.

You may want to try is to create a class that will store the data that you store in form of map, and writing proper `hashcode()` and `equals()` implementation you will simplify the code.

Answer (score 1):

In theory,you can do that. The java compiler won't complain anything about it.

**But in reality, it is recommended not to use any object whose hashCode() is updatable as the key.** The reason is that hashCode of the key will be used by the LinkedHashMap (in fact, it is its super class HashMap) when hashing the entries, and lookup a certain key.

For a better understanding, you would meet the following problem using the code:

```java
LinkedHashMap<Map<String, Integer>, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> key1 = new HashMap<>();
key1.put("one", 1);
map.put(key1, "value associated with key1");

// this would print: true
System.out.println(map.containsKey(key1));

key1.put("two", 2);

// after previous statement, the map key1 has a new hashCode()

// this would print: false
// The reason is: the hashCode() method of HashMap is based on all
// the entries it contains. Since previous key1.put("two", 2)
// cause a new entry added into the map, thus the hashCode() of
// key1 has changed. In the meantime, the LinkedHashMap didn't
// rehash which means the key1 is still hashed using the old
// hashCode. This furthur lead to the LinkedHashMap.containsKey()
// cannot find the key1 by comparing the new hashCode and the old
// one 
System.out.println(map.containsKey(key1));
```